# Any easy solution to resolve pickling error

Tags: python

I am using savez to save the weights. Following is my code:

```
class vgg16:
    def __init__(self, imgs1,imgs2, weights=None, sess=None):
    .........

        self.weight_list=[]
        self.keys=[]

       ........
    self.SaveWeights()
....neural network............
def SaveWeights(self):

    tmp = file("vgg16_predict.npz",'wb')
    np.savez(self,**dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
    tmp.close
```

I keep getting the pickling error. There are different solutions provided. But is there an easiest way to make this happen?
Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f.py", line 350, in <module>
    vgg = vgg16(imgs1,imgs2, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)
  File "f.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.SaveWeights()
  File "f.py", line 339, in SaveWeights
    np.savez(self,**dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 574, in savez
    _savez(file, args, kwds, False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 639, in _savez
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 573, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'module'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.module failed
Exception AttributeError: "vgg16 instance has no attribute 'tell'" in <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7f812dec99d0>> ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pickle to a file. Just use the path directly:

```
np.savez("vgg16_predict.npz", **dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
```

So, this should be you full method:

```
def SaveWeights(self):
    np.savez("vgg16_predict.npz", **dict(zip(self.keys, self.weight_list)))
```

Comment: Please show your full `def SaveWeights(self):`  with right indentation.

Comment: These are the only statements in this function

Comment: I do not already have a file named"vgg16_predict". Could this be raising the issue?

Comment: It will create  this file. Try the `def SaveWeights(self):` from my answer. Make sure to use the right file. You should not get your error anymore.

Comment: It s giving the attribute error but error is still raised. Should I give absolute path to file? And list is appended like this:self.parameters += [kernel, biases]
     self.keys.append('conv1_1')
     self.weight_list.append(self.parameters). Could this be a problem?

Comment: What AttributeError? `"vgg16 instance has no attribute 'tell'"`? This should not happen if you have  `np.savez("vgg16_predict.npz",`

Comment: Sorry for the typeo. It is not giving attribute error